# Time.new subtracting 6 hours AND tacking on CST -6 on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, heroku, time

I'm sure there's some conversion thing I'm looking over here.

On Heroku's console,

```
irb(main):052:0> Time.new(2014, 1, 21)
=> 2014-01-21 00:00:00 +0000
```

However, setting a column to that:

```
irb(main):042:0> PressRelease.first.update_attribute :published_on, Time.new(2014, 1, 21)
  PressRelease Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "press_releases".* FROM "press_releases" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
  FriendlyId::Slug Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "friendly_id_slugs".* FROM "friendly_id_slugs" WHERE "friendly_id_slugs"."sluggable_id" = 1 AND "friendly_id_slugs"."sluggable_type" = 'PressRelease' ORDER BY "friendly_id_slugs".id DESC LIMIT 1
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

Gives this date:

```
=> Mon, 20 Jan 2014 18:00:00 CST -06:00
```

To clarify, `application.rb` does indeed have the time zone set:

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

And when I check on their console:

```
irb(main):054:0> Time.zone
=> (GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
```

However, doing this locally works fine:

```
1.9.3-p448 :011 > Time.new(2014, 1, 21)
 => 2014-01-21 00:00:00 -0600
```

So, it looks like Heroku is subtracting -6 (since our Time Zone is set to CST -6), then tacking on the timezone of CST -6 as well. Why? This is, as you can see, messing up date-specific items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Rails to use the `time_zone` setting, you need to use the wrappers provided by `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`.  See docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Here's an example:

```
Time.zone.parse("2014-1-21")
# Outputs Tue, 21 Jan 2014 00:00:00 MST -07:00
```